# Debian GNOME 2.30, desktop does not respond anymore

Tags: debian, gnome, desktop

I have Debian Wheezy with GNOME (2.30.2) installed on my computer and my problem is that my desktop does not work anymore.

I can't right click on the desktop (to change wallpaper, etc...). Moreover, I don't see my files & folders on the desktop, however by using nautilus I can see that the Desktop folder still exists (and all his content).

I don't know where to find the mistake I've certainly done. The steps I took:

```
apt-get install nautilus-share
apt-get update/upgrade
```

Comment: Have you already tried rebooting? Also, isn't there an option in Gnome where you can choose to hide your desktop? If there is I would double check to make sure it isn't toggled by mistake.

Comment: What happens if you open a terminal and just run `nautilus`?

Comment: @ean5533 It works, It runs my file manager and I can see my home folder.

Comment: @MaxMackie : I rebooted several times, I removed (--purge) nautilus-share (dunno if it's related to my problem), and it doesn't change anything

Comment: Try running `nautilus` from the terminal and logging out and back in.

Comment: @MaxMackie : Ok I try this. Maybe you're right, it's just that my option says hide the desktop. I try with `gconf-editor` to change it, but can't find where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements of [Gnome 3](http://www.gnome.org/gnome-3/) have begun to make their way into Wheezy. gnome-shell does not show files on the desktop and uses a new settings application called `gnome-control-center` to manage backgrounds instead of a right-click menu.

You could also use [`gnome-tweak-tool`](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeTweakTool) to restore the old functionality of the desktop (by having the file manager, nautilus, manage it instead of gnome-shell).