# kde install destroys gnome desktop

Tags: kde, gnome3

I recently installed KDE 4.7 on my wife's computer. I did not use the recommended Debian 'install task' method, which emulates the full install-from-.iso process.

Instead I just did:

```
# apt-get install kde-plasma-workspace plasma*
```

She uses GNOME, and wanted KDE because apparently you can take advantage of some additional features in kdenlive when you are running it from KDE. And so I opted to keep both WMs going. Unfortunately, I was not prepared for the consequences of installing two WMs on the same machine. In this case, installing KDE rendered the GNOME *desktop* non-functional, though not GNOME itself, as in this question: [Debian GNOME 2.30, desktop does not respond anymore](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24214/gnome-2-3-desktop-does-not-respond-anymore).

Dolphin also made itself the default file manager in GNOME (gdm3), which was a headache. I removed Dolphin, and I have basically removed KDE, but it has not fixed anything of course.

Comment: did u manage to fix this

Comment: never. i just installed kde from scratch.

Comment: you mean u re-installed Debian?

Comment: yep. i couldn't find a fix for it.